# Log spam with "unable to find container named fluentd-gcp"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, fluentd

Last night my Kubernetes cluster on GKE was upgraded to 1.16.8-gke.9. Since then the logs show `error: unable to find container named fluentd-gcp` every minute. Logging from my applications still works, but I'd like to know what causes this error and how to get rid of this.

Expanding the error yields slightly more details:

```
{
  "textPayload": "error: unable to find container named fluentd-gcp\n",
  "insertId": "v1b2u2ldrnswujhz2",
  "resource": {
    "type": "k8s_container",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "foo",
      "pod_name": "fluentd-gke-scaler-cd4d654d7-tgg27",
      "cluster_name": "foo-cluster",
      "container_name": "fluentd-gke-scaler",
      "namespace_name": "kube-system",
      "location": "us-east1-d"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-04-24T16:15:40.224944500Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "gke.googleapis.com/log_type": "system",
    "k8s-pod/k8s-app": "fluentd-gke-scaler",
    "k8s-pod/pod-template-hash": "cd4d654d7"
  },
  "logName": "projects/foo/logs/stderr",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-04-24T16:15:45.923960735Z"
}
```

`kubectl get all --all-namespaces` shows `fluentd-gke` pods with a `fluentd-gke` container, not `fluentd-gcp`.

Any advice would be appreciated and I'm happy to post more details, if you tell me where to look for them.

**Edit: More details and related problems on the GKE issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156965162**

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @DanielKobe No. It's a GKE problem, apparently it's trying to use the wrong image for fluentd. Logging still works and I just filter out this line for now, easier than changing the cluster to a Stable release unfortunately.

Comment: Here is the corresponding issue on the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156965162

Comment: @sekl, can you write as an answer to your question? Finding a solution by yourself is the best way to solve other problems too :) 
If not, I'll

Comment: @confiq It's not really solved yet, I'm just waiting for a patch to be honest. I'll update here once the problem is actually fixed.

Comment: it's your call, however that was the best answer to this question... Although it's not the solution, it is an answer to what problem is @sekl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in `GKE 1.16.9-gke.6` according to the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156965162

Answer (score 1):

1.16.8-gke.9 is currently being offered through rapid channel. Keep in mind that such a channel is offered on an early access basis for people to test new releases, as such the version offered may be subject to unresolved issues with no known workaround. That said a possible fix could be to drain and [migrate your workloads to another node](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool). If issue persists, then create an issue [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, however this cluster is on the "Regular" release channel. I will try the work-around anyway and am considering switching to Stable all-together.

Comment: Migrating to a new node pool didn't help unfortunately. Also: "[Google Kubernetes Engine will gradually upgrade clusters in the regular channel to GKE 1.16 beginning on or after April 13, 2020.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes)" - so that explains the automatic upgrade.